# input validation for numeric input

Tags: c++, linux, validation

I'm very new to this C++ world and trying write a input validation function for numeric password. This is what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

void isNumeric(int &iN)
{
    while (1) {
        cin >> iN;

        if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Only 'numeric' value(s) are allowed: ";
            continue;
        }

        // alpha-numeric entry also not allowed 
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if (cin.gcount() >  1) continue;

        // check against the -ve value
        if (iN <= 0 ) continue;

    break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x;

    cout << "Enter your number: ";
    isNumeric(x);
    cout << "You've entered: " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's working just fine for incorrect value(s) but not breaking out of the loop upon valid entry. Any idea what I'm missing here? Cheers!!

---

**ErroR from James Kanze's script:**

```
test.cpp: In function ‘bool parseNumber(const string&, int&)’:
test.cpp:11:20: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘text >> results’
test.cpp:11:20: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.tcc:998:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:957:5: note: template<class _CharT2, class _Traits2> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT2*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/istream.tcc:925:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:709:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:714:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:756:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:761:5: note: template<class _Traits> std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, _Traits>&, signed char*)
test.cpp:11:42: error: ‘const string’ has no member named ‘peek’
test.cpp:11:52: error: ‘EOF’ was not declared in this scope
```

---

New code: *using **`getline()`** and **validation as a string*** 
Thanks everyone (especially James Kanze) for helping me out. This thing is pretty much working here.

```
void isNumeric( int &iN )
{
    string sN; 

    while (1) {
        getline(cin, sN);

        bool valNum = true;
        for ( unsigned iDx=0; iDx < sN.length(); iDx++ )
            if ( !isdigit(sN[iDx]) ) { 
                valNum = false;
                break;
            }   

        if ( !valNum ) { 
            cout << "Wrong entry; Try again: ";
            continue;
        }   

        stringstream sStream (sN );
        sStream >> iN; 

        if ( iN<=0 ) {
            cout << "Cannot be 0; Try again: "; 
            continue;
        }     
    break;   
    }   
}
```

Is there any room in there for any more improvement?  Cheers!!

Comment: @Shahbaz I always knew my c++ is hopeless but didn't know it has gone that far!

Comment: It's not about your code, your question title somehow reminded me of this funny I saw once!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like line oriented input.  In which case, the usual solution
is to use `getline`:

```
bool parseNumber( std::string const& text, int& results )
{
    std::istringstream parser( text );
    return parser >> results >> std::ws && parser.peek() == EOF;
}

int getNumber()
{
    int results;
    std::string line;
    while ( ! std::getline( std::cin, line ) || ! parseNumber( line, results ) ) 
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "Only 'numeric' value(s) allowed:";
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `getline()` missing the second parameter?

Comment: @James Kanze: it returns this error: `error: variable ‘std::istringstream parser’ has initializer but incomplete type` - what does it mean? cheers!!

Comment: @jrok Yes.  it should be `std::getline( std::cin, line )`.

Comment: @MacUsers It means that you're missing an include.  Add `#include <sstream>` at the top of the file.

Comment: `#include <sstream>` - yes that's what I was looking for. On a separate note, where can I find the info like this?  i.e. what needs to be included for a certain module (is it called 'module'?)? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers Any documentation on `istringstream` or `ostringstream` _should_ contain it.  Whether it does or not is another question; I've not been impressed by the quality of documentation I've seen in general (and the first hits I got when googling `istringstream` didn't mention the include, although at least two pretended to be "reference" sites).

Comment: @James Kanze: Thanks for the info. Now, w.r.t the code, is it working for you? I'm getting loads of errors. I think, the it should be `return text >> results ....` instead of just `result` and the ending `(` is missing in the while statement, which I've already fixed. The compete error messages are added in the OP. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers The actual code was typed in quickly, off the top of my head, and likely does contain errors.  It was meant more as a push in the right direction.  With regards to the last line of `parseNumber`, there's an obvious typo, it should start `return parser ...`.  I'll edit to fix it.  (I answer questions here while waiting for the compiler to finish.  In this case, it obviously finished before I was through, with the result that I didn't reread what I'd typed.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Don't worry, I understood; I actually got a lot to do to catch up with the c++ error messaging. BTW, I thought `getline()` is extremely useful for the input with white space in it e.g. Full Name - isn't it?

Comment: One more thing: Using `using namespace std;` in the beginning makes less typing down the line. Is there any reason not to use that and carry on with `std::XX` instead? I see a lot of guys here do that. Any specific reason for that? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers `getline` is useful for a lot of things.  In general, anytime the input is line oriented, I'll use `getline` to read a line at a time, and then parse the line, either with an `istringstream` or using regular expressions.  This makes resynchronization extremely simple.

Comment: @MacUsers With regards to `using namespace std;`, there are so many things in `std::` that no one really knows them off the top of there head.  Avoiding the `using`, and being explicit, avoids possible ambiguities, and tells the reader exactly where to look for the documentation when he sees the function being used.  (This is more a problem in larger applications.  For small, one man projects, the `using` is fine.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I've updated my post with the new code, following your guideline. Is it something do you think better? I'm still using `using namespace std;` thing; shall change that later. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers I'd just use `istringstream sStream( sN );`, rather than a bidirectional stream.  Logically, I'm inputting from the string `sN` (or at least that's how I look at it).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Changed now. I still need to use `sStream >> iN;`, otherwise `if ( iN<=0 )` part doesn't get checked when call the function like this: `int iX;  isNumeric(iX);`. This is expected - isn't it? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers You have to check for negative yourself, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a failure to convert then the stream itself evaluates to false so you can do this:

```
int get_int() {
    int i;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number: " << std::endl;
    while(!(std::cin >> i)) {
        std::cin.clear();   //clear flags
        //discard bad input
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()); 
        std::cout << "Incorrect, must be numeric: " << std::endl;
    }
    return i;
 }
```

Comment: It's not actually doing what I intend to do. An input like this: `123asd`, should be rejected but it's accepting `123` (as expected). And if I enter: `asd123`, it doesn't do anything at all. Cheers!!

Comment: This will succeed if the user enters `"1abc"`.

Comment: @James Kanze: That's some thing I don't want. My goal is: Anything else other than numeric values should be rejected. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers That means that you shouldn't use `std::ignore`.  My preference is still to read a complete line, using `std::getline`, and then parse it, consuming all of the characters in it.  For validation, you can just read an `int`, followed by whitespace, then check that you have end of file, or you can pre-validate using regular expressions: "\\s+\\d+\\s+", for example.  (This has the advantage/disadvantage that is will reject negative numbers.)  The regex solution is the most general, but in this case, is probably overkill.