# Where did I go wrong coding in CPP to incrementally count the amount of times a word occurs in a text file?

Tags: c++, try-catch, text-files, word-count

**EDIT:** Code updated using tips from SO replies. I get no errors when compiling, the list prints empty. Quantities are not updating.

**Original Post:**
This is for school and I can't seem to get it to increment the items. It opens the file successfully but then prints 0 for occurrences even though there are at minimum 1 for each item I enter in the menu. This isn't my entire code but it's the code for my class since I think that's likely where I went wrong. Additionally, my menu won't recognize invalid input even though the else portion of the if/else is there to catch it. It just enters an infinite loop of printing the menu. I am open to all feedback and/or links to resources better than Zybooks to teach me what I am missing here.

```
class ItemCounter {
private:
    map <string, int> itemFrequency;
    string inputFile = "CS210_Project_Three_Input_File.txt";
    string outputFile = "itemTracker.dat";
public:
    void loadInputFile() {
        ifstream file(inputFile);
        // OPEN conditions
        if (file.is_open()) {
            string itemName;
            while (getline(file, itemName)) {
                int itemQuantity = 0;
                // Update item count
                itemFrequency[itemName] += itemQuantity;

                // Exception check for string conversion
                try {
                    itemQuantity = stoi(itemName);
                }
                catch (const invalid_argument& e) {
                    cout << "Error: Invalid Entry Found in Input File." << endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // Close open file
            file.close();
        }
        // Else statement if file won't open
        else {
            cout << "Error: Could Not Open Input File" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    // Function to save new data to external file
    void saveOutputFile() {
        ofstream file(outputFile);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            for (auto& item : itemFrequency) {
                file << item.first << " " << item.second << endl;
            }
            file.close();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error: Could Not Open Output File - Data Not Saved" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    // Function to display item occurrences
    void displayItemCount(string itemName) {
        int count = itemFrequency[itemName];
        cout << "Total Item Occurances for " << itemName << ": " << count << endl;

    }

    //Function to count and display total item counts of whole list
    void displayTotals () {
        for (auto& item : itemFrequency) {
            cout << item.first << " " << item.second << endl;
        }
    }

    // Function to count items in the list and print as histogram
    void displayItemsHistogram() {
        for (auto& item : itemFrequency) {
            cout << item.first << " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < item.second; i++) {
                cout << "*";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
    // Function to save new data to external file
    void saveOutputFile() {
        ofstream file(outputFile);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            for (auto& item : itemFrequency) {
                file << item.first << " " << item.second << endl;
            }
            file.close();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error: Could Not Open Output File - Data Not Saved" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() { 
    ItemCounter itemCounter;
    itemCounter.loadInputFile();
    itemCounter.saveOutputFile();
    int menuChoice = 0;

    while (menuChoice != 4) {
        cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "1. Stuff" << endl;
        cout << "2. Stuff" << endl;
        cout << "3. Stuff" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please make a selection: ";
        cin >> menuChoice;
        cout << endl;

        if (menuChoice == 1) {
            string itemName;
            cout << "Enter search term: ";
            cin >> itemName;
            cout << "FIX ME:" << endl;
        }

        else if (menuChoice == 2) {
            cout << "FIX ME" << endl;
        }

        else if (menuChoice == 3) {
            cout << "FIX ME" << endl;
        }
            
        else if (menuChoice == 4) {
            cout << "Program Terminated" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid Selection, try again." << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Read in data from file errors]

[image: Display list from file quantity fails to update]

Comment: `int itemQuantity; itemFrequency[itemName] += itemQuantity;` What value do you expect `itemQuantity` to have here? What value should it have?

Comment: Using `std::istringstream` and `std::unordered_map<string, int>` would eliminate chunks of the code you have now.  There wouldn't need to be any checking of spaces, and the counter automatically gets incremented.

Comment: @Nathan --  int itemQuantity starts at 0 and increments as the entered itemName is read from the list in the txt file.

Comment: `std::string word; std::istringstream strm(line); while (line >> word) { itemFrequency[itemWord]++; }` -- No need for `substr()`, no need to check for spaces, and the error pointed out in the comment by @NathanPierson doesn't show up.  Also, the `itemQuantity` is simply `itemFrequency.size();`

Comment: @K_B That is incorrect. `itemQuantity` starts with an indeterminate value because you didn't initialize it. It sounds like your goal was for `itemFrequency[itemName]` to start at `0` and go up by `1` each time `itemName` is read. But that's not what you wrote.

Comment: Note: You don't need to explicitly call `close` on a file stream in this scenario; the destructor will take care of this. (It's not wrong to do this though.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie our course has us putting "using namespace std;" at the top of our code so that's why I don't have std in front of everything. I will look up the other bits you suggested and see if that helps my brain.

Comment: @K_B *our course has us putting "using namespace std;" at the top of our code* -- Given that this is inline inside a `class`, your course is teaching bad habits.  The `using namespace std;` should never go in a header file.

Comment: A [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) is probably missing from your code...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- our course is 100% teaching us bad habits, I've been told this before. 
@fabian -- I had a try/catch in my code with 

`try {
   itemQuantity = stoi(itemCountStr);
   }
catch (const invalid_argument& e) {
   cout << "Error: Invalid Entry Found in Input File." << endl;
   continue;
   }`

But I deleted it, probably against my better judgement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480108/920069 has a basic example of how to handle bad input. You can search for many more examples.

Comment: What is the format of your input like? `itemQuantity = stoi(itemName);` doesn't make a lot of sense. `itemName` is presumably a string like `"Apples"`, which cannot be converted into an integer.

Comment: @NathanPierson I thought that I was basically converting it to a number so I could add them together and get the total count of apples. Or total count of onions. This is for a grocery store counting the number of each items sold in a day.

Comment: Basically converting _what_ to a number? What number should the string `"Apples"` be converted to? Or is the format of your input file something like `Apples 10 Pears 50 Squash 0` and you need code that will 1.) Read the value of `10` in and 2.) Convert it to the integer `10`?

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going with this. The list is just a list of produce items. I want to count the amount of times a word is in the list. I threw out the conversion parts and changed it to an if statement but alas, no incrementing is happening. 

`if (file.is_open()) {
            string itemName;
            int itemQuantity = 0;

            while (file.peek() != EOF) {
                getline(file, itemName);

                // Update item count
                if (itemName == itemName) {
                    itemFrequency[itemName] += itemQuantity;
                }
`

Comment: What do you think `itemFrequency[itemName] += itemQuantity;` is going to do if `itemQuantity` is 0? When do you think `if(itemName == itemName)` might possibly be false?

Answer (score 1):

Issue with counting occurrences:

In the `loadInputFile()` function, you are initializing `itemQuantity` without assigning any value to it before using it to increment `itemFrequency[itemName]`. This means that you are incrementing with an uninitialized value, leading to incorrect results.

To fix this, you should convert `itemCountStr` to an integer and assign it to `itemQuantity` before incrementing `itemFrequency[itemName]`.

Replace the line:

```
int itemQuantity;
```

with:

```
int itemQuantity = stoi(itemCountStr);
```

Issue with invalid input handling:

In the `while` loop in `main()`, if the user enters an invalid selection (a value other than 1, 2, 3, or 4), the program should not continue to print the menu indefinitely.

To address this, you can add a `break;` statement in the `else` block to exit the loop.

Replace:

```
else {
    cout << "Invalid Selection, try again." << endl;
}
```

with:

```
else {
    cout << "Invalid Selection, try again." << endl;
    break;
}
```

With these modifications, the code should now correctly increment the item occurrences, and handle invalid input by breaking out of the menu loop when necessary.

Comment: I am still getting a return value of 0 when I enter the search term after changing the itemQuantity line. For the menu error, adding break terminates the program, but doesn't let the user enter another selection.